# VPN - Cisco 2800 Series Router and Cisco ASA

Tags: vpn, cisco, server-message-block, cisco-asa

What I currently have:
Windows 2003/2008 servers supporting a 150 user environment.
Linksys RV082 Router (HQ) and RV042 (satellite) routers
Site to Site VPN Tunneling to 5 satellite (< 10 user) offices

What I need:
End-user VPN allowing myself and users to connect remotely to my network

I need to replace our current routers and have been recommended the 2811 Router.  Can this router alone be enough to get what I need (VPN tunnelling for users and site to site VPN) or will I require purchasing an additional ASA appliance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cisco 2811 will need the AIM-EPII-PLUS Module, but yes, it can support VPN Connections.

Comment: Is it more cost-effective to purchase the VPN module versus purchasing a Cisco ASA?

Comment: A 2811 with AIM installed will run around $2000. An ASA5505 with VPN installed will be about $1500. An ASA5510 around $3000. The ASA5510 is the most powerful of the three, and the 5505 the least. These are very general ballpark prices, and will vary depending on your network, exact features, and who you buy from.
Where I work, we use an ASA5510 at our main office, and ASA5505 unites at two branch offices.

Comment: One other note, the ASA5505 doesn't have a T1 port, so it can't completely replace the unit you have now. The 2811 does have this capability (depending on what router you currently have, the WIC may simply swap right over).

Comment: Thanks for your recommendations, Chris S. I am going to make a decision shortly but I am leaning towards getting a 2811 or 2911 (for load balancing 2 ISPs - E1 and cable) which will do routing and an ASA 5510 for our DMZ (webmail/www) and VPN needs (site to site and client to site).  I presume this is a do-able scenario?